# Trouble with MVC 5 and ambient route parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

[Link to my sample project](https://github.com/PrintsCharming/MVCRoutingIssue)

In the project above (MVC 5) I am having issues with Html.ActionLink seemingly not clearing out the routing parameters from the page its currently on.

The exact same call to Html.ActionLink on one page produces different results depending on how "deep" into the route you are. Below is my Sample Controller

```
    // GET: Sample
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    [Route("sample/example/{categoryid}")]
    public ActionResult Example(int categoryID)
    {
        ViewBag.categoryID = categoryID;
        return View("Example");
    }

    [Route("sample/example/{parentcategoryid:int}/{categorydepth:int}")]
    public ActionResult Example(int parentcategoryID, int categorydepth)
    {
        ViewBag.parentcategoryID = parentcategoryID;
        ViewBag.categorydepth = categorydepth;
        return View("Example");
    }
```

Below is a snippet from the Sample/Index view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Example", new { controller = "Sample", categoryid = 100 }, null)
```

This produces the following HTML: `http://localhost:2762/sample/example/100`

Below is a snippet from Sample/Example view

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Link", "Example", new { controller = "Sample", categoryid = 100 }, null)

<br />

@Html.ActionLink("Deeper Link", "Example", new { controller="Sample", parentcategoryid=9999, categorydepth=2})
```

The first time you get there by clicking the link from the Index view...the "Link" Html is the same: `http://localhost:2762/sample/example/100`

If you click "Deeper Link", you get this same view again...however the "Link" Html is now: `http://localhost:2762/sample/example/9999/2?categoryid=100` which clearly does not go where you'd like it to go.

This is basically a breadcrumb scenario for browsing product categories.

Any thoughts on a clean and manageable fix for this?

Comment: I know this may seem weird, but if you put your method with the longer route before the other one what happens?  The problem is that because they use the same prefix route, the one that uses categoryid will always be chosen if it is first in the routes collection.

Comment: No change...still has the incorrect parameters after clicking the "Deeper Link"

Comment: Interestingly...if I swap the order values (as per the suggestion in the answer that was deleted), the problem swaps too. The errant link is on Deeper Link when you first visit the page. O_o

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't mention this before, but changing the method names to be unique will definitely resolve your issue.

Comment: Changing the method name (but leaving the routing) resulted in the "Link" url to be http://localhost:2762/Sample/Example?categoryid=100 So frustrating. I was trying to avoid a mishmosh of route names. Might short term solution is going to be crafting the link old school...but that doesn't help if routes change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Example() to Example2() in the controller

Comment: I did that, see the last comment on the question.

Comment: I was originally trying to keep the Action the same and use overloaded parameters with routing...but I guess that was futile. This worked after I changed the Action name in the ActionLink method...which is weird because I thought Action would match to the route established not the method name.